# Access argument string for all administrators to access menu

Tags: routes, users

I have implemented a hook_menu method in a module i'm writing.

The problem i'm facing is, i'm not able to pass an access argument that grants access to all the administrators.

The only one able to access the page is the admin account that was made upon installation.

Any help would be appreciated. This is the code.

```
function raffle_menu()
{
    $items = array();

    $items['admin/config/people/raffle'] = array(
        'title' => 'Raffle',
        'access callback' => 'user_access',
        'access arguments' => array('administer site configuration'),
        'file' => 'raffle_admin.inc',
        'page callback' => 'raffle_abc_view',
    );
    return $items;
}
```

Comment: have you defined raffle_permission function in your module?

Comment: oops. No, i didn't know that was necessary.

Comment: Yes, It is necessary!

Comment: @ShabirA. I used the hook_permissions hook, and enabled that permission for all my administrators. If i'm correct, now i just pass that permission to the access argument?

Comment: see my answer. and yes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining your module in hook_menu is not enough. You need to define [hook_permission()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_permission/7) too. You can do something like this

```
function raffle_permission() {
   return array(
    'administer site configuration' => array(
      'title' => t('Administer Site Configuration'),
      'description' => t('Perform administration tasks for my module.'),
    ),
  );
}
```